# Capture the content within an environment

Tags: environments

When working in latex I can do an environment like

```
\begin{some}
stuff
\end{some}
```

and stuff happen and I can define my own environments, I am working on something and what I want to do is essentially to grab everything that was "stuff" in the example and do something to it during the end part of the definition, how would I go about that?

Comment: Without more details of what you really want to do it is difficult to say for sure but I think that you want the [environ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ) package.

Comment: You can use the `environ` package then do `\NewEnviron{some}{Do things with \BODY}`. Then when you call `\begin{some}
stuff
\end{some}` you get `Do things with stuff`.

Comment: currently I am experimentating I just need a way to access the "stuff" part and by the sound, environ is it, imma try

Comment: works dandy, thanks guys! :D anyone wanting the rep just write the answer and I'll accept it

Comment: If it contains verbatim content see also [macros - Collect contents of an environment (that contains verbatim content) - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/373647/collect-contents-of-an-environment-that-contains-verbatim-content)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this you can use the [`environ` package](//ctan.org/pkg/environ)'s `\NewEnviron{<env>}` definition. The environment contents is captured inside `\BODY` that you can set as-is, or manipulate however you want.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{some}{%
  \BODY% Print the body of the some environment

  \renewcommand{\thisorthat}{that}% Update
  \BODY% Print the body of the some environment
}

\newcommand{\thisorthat}{this}

\begin{document}

\begin{some}
  It's either \thisorthat, or \thisorthat.
\end{some}

\end{document}
```