# \begin{myenv} ended by \end{document}

Tags: environments

For a `pandoc` application, I want to use a custom environment.
The environment's definition varies depending on a pandoc variable I defined (btw awesome feature!).

To manipulate the environment's content, I used the `environ` package as suggested here: [Capture the content within an environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/436165/capture-the-content-within-an-environment)

To use markdown inside begin-end inside my source file, I used the trick suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41005796/1406122

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}

% some example environment
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{MyEnvironment}{%
%  Depends... :) %
%  \textsl{\BODY}
  This content is hidden.
}

% some example environment
\newenvironment{myenvironment}%
  {\bgroup\slshape}%
  {\egroup}

% hide stuff from PANDOC
\let\Begin\begin
\let\End\end

\begin{document}

Some text.

\Begin{MyEnvironment}
\begin{itemize}
\item Some itemized content
\end{itemize}
\End{MyEnvironment}

\end{document}
```

However, these two tips don't mix well!

> LaTeX Error: \begin{MyEnvironment} on input line 24 ended by \end{document}.

If the standard environment `myenvironment` is used instead, the above example compiles as expected. Yet with normal environments I can't modify its body content.

**P.S.**: To give some context, this was translated from a source MD-file:

```
Some text.

\Begin{MyEnvironment}

- Some itemized content

\End{MyEnvironment}
```

Comment: And environ construction will look for an explicit string `\end{env}`, so why exactly are you using `\Begin` and `\End`?

Comment: `\begin` and `\end` are treated differently by pandoc (markdown inside begin-end is not parsed, ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40982836/latex-multicolumn-block-in-pandoc-markdown

Comment: Then you'll probably need a personally readjusted version of `environ`, not something I can help with at the moment. But you should adjust your question so others can better understand the need for `\Begin/End`