# Save the content of an environment containing \verb or \lstinline

Tags: macros, environments, verbatim, expansion

I wish to copy the content of an environment into a macro (or into a temp file). Previously I use the following code:

```
\usepackage{environ}
\def\SavedContent{}
\NewEnviron{savecontent}{%
    \BODY%
    % \global\let\SavedContent\BODY%
    \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\SavedContent\expandafter{\BODY}
}
```

However, this method doesn't work if there's `\verb` or `\lstinline` inside the environment.

Later I discovered [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/373647/194994). An answer describes a working way as:

> ... implement an environment that reads its body verbatimized and then within a macro definition wraps things ...

Unfortunately, the answer is too complicated for me to understand. Thus I would like to ask: how should one define the `savecontent` environment correctly?

**Add: The content doesn't have to be stored into a macro. It would also work if one can save the content into a file and read it later. How could one achieve this?**

*The motivation of this question is that I want to save the content of the abstract and show it later.*

Below is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ}

\def\SavedContent{}
\NewEnviron{savecontent}{%
    \BODY%
    % \global\let\SavedContent\BODY%
    \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\SavedContent\expandafter{\BODY}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{savecontent}
    Some text
\end{savecontent}
\SavedContent

% \begin{savecontent}
%     \verb|code|
% \end{savecontent}
% \SavedContent

\end{document}
```

Comment: As David wrote in the comment under the other question:  if you have mixture of verbatim and text it won't work. You are freezing the catcodes when storing in a command, and then verb can't do its work. Write your content to a file and read it in again.

Comment: Are you free to use LuaLaTeX? If you are, please take a look at [How to handle verbatim material in LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361738/5001).

Answer (score 1):

If you're free to use LuaLaTeX, the following solution may be of interest to you. It's a slightly simplified version of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/361759/5001). Just copy the code between the lines `%%% >>>>>` and `%%% <<<<<` to your preamble, surround the verbatim material you wish to save with `\Verbatim` and `\EndVerbatim` lines, and use `\printverbatim` and `\useverbatim` as needed.

In the earlier answer, I provide a lot more background information about how this approach works and why the code is "bullet proof", in the sense that the verbatim material can be pretty much anything.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}  % for filler text

%%% >>>>>
\usepackage{luacode} % for "luacode" environment
%% Lua-side code: define 1 Lua table and 3 Lua functions
\begin{luacode}
verb_table = {}
function store_lines ( s )
  if s:find ( "\\EndVerbatim" ) then
    luatexbase.remove_from_callback (
      "process_input_buffer" , "store_lines")
  else
    table.insert ( verb_table , s )
  end
  return ""
end
function register_verbatim ()
  verb_table = {}
  luatexbase.add_to_callback(
    "process_input_buffer" , store_lines , "store_lines")
end
function print_lines ( catcode )
  if catcode then
    tex.print ( catcode , verb_table)
  else
    tex.print ( verb_table )
  end
end
\end{luacode}

%% TeX-side code: define several LaTeX macros
\def\Verbatim{\directlua{register_verbatim()}}
\def\useverbatim{\directlua{print_lines()}}
\def\printverbatim{%
  \par
  \bgroup
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
  \ttfamily
  \directlua{print_lines(1)}
  \egroup
}
\def\createcatcodes{%
  \bgroup
  \catcode`\\=12 \catcode`\{=12 \catcode`\}=12
  \catcode`\$=12 \catcode`\&=12 \catcode`\^^M=13
  \catcode`\#=12 \catcode`\^=12 \catcode`\_=12
  \catcode`\ =13 \catcode`\~=12 \catcode`\%=12
  \savecatcodetable 1 % '\savecatcodetable' is a LuaTeX primitive
  \egroup}
\createcatcodes
\def\Space{ }
\bgroup
\catcode`\^^M=13\gdef^^M{\quitvmode\par}%
\catcode`\ = 13\gdef {\quitvmode\Space}%
\egroup
%%% <<<<<

\begin{document}

\Verbatim
\begin{abstract}
\noindent
\lipsum[1][1-7] % output first 7 sentences of first para
\end{abstract}
\EndVerbatim

\hrule\smallskip

\printverbatim

\smallskip\hrule

\useverbatim

\hrule
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a partial solution, only saves the content of the last `savecontent` environment. The `savecontent` environment saves its content to a file `\jobname.mytmp`, the macro `\SavedContent` then read this file as input. It uses `\VerbatimOut` of `fancyvrb`, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37794/194994) of @egreg.

If one wish to save the content in all of the `savecontent` environments, one may consider using a counter to mark the corresponding environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\def\SavedContent{\input{\jobname.mytmp}}
\newenvironment{savecontent}{%
    \VerbatimOut{\jobname.mytmp}%
}{
    \endVerbatimOut%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{savecontent}
    Some text
\end{savecontent}
\SavedContent

\begin{savecontent}
    \verb|code|
\end{savecontent}
\SavedContent

\end{document}
```

Comment: What if you have two, or more, `savecontent` bofore any `\SavedContent`?