# Recording the contents between two macros and save them for later usage

Tags: macros, environments, expl3

Is it possible to define such two macros `\start_recording:` and `\stop_recording:`, so that everything between them can be saved (*possibly verbatimly*) to `\the_recording_tl`, and when applying `\the_recording_tl` one can obtain again those contents in the document?

This is almost the same demand as in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/184503). But I am expecting something clever with `expl3`, which is merely mentioned there.

---

*The motivation of this question is that I would like to save the content of some environments (for example the abstract and proofs) and show them later. In an old package, I did this by using `fancyvrb`'s `VerbatimOut` environment to write them to auxiliary files and read them in later (see, e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/596239)). However, this approach seems to be quite messy and it has the side effect that contents on the same line with `\start_recording:` will sometimes lead to errors or lost of data.*

Comment: Take a look at the `scontents` package:  it does (if I understood) exactly what you want

Comment: Personally I feel like `expl3` is great for programming logic. For a lot of catcode trickery, using traditional LaTeX interfaces is probably more convenient. I don't see why the `xparse` solution doesn't work for now.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you, I just realized that there is such a wonderful package!

Comment: @AlanXiang I get it. By the way, thank you so much for your `expl3` guide, it really helps a lot for a beginner.